# Facilitating Job Title Normalization

Tags: normalization

So I am aware of how I could go about this myself, but anybody aware of any existing libraries which could handle this? (whatever language)?

Answer (score 0):

This API is English-only, and has job title normalization: http://api.dataatwork.org/v1/spec/